# How to include servlet jar in a gradle project with jetty runner?

Tags: servlets, gradle, jetty

I'm using android studio 1.3. I've installed the jetty runner plugin from here:

https://github.com/guikeller/jetty-runner

I need to extend HttpServlet, so I include the following dependency in build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0-alpha-1'
}
```

which causes a NoSuchMethod exception at jetty startup for the method:

```
ServletContext.getServletRegistration
```

Some of the stack trace:

```
INFO::main: Logging initialized @131ms
INFO:oejr.Runner:main: Runner
INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.5.v20141112
WARN:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: ServletContainerInitializers: detected. 
    Class hierarchy: empty
WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED
    org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.ServletContainerInitializersStarter:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
javax.servlet.ServletContext.getServletRegistration(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/servlet/ServletRegistration;
...
```

If I don't include the servlet jar dependency, the runner works ok (but I can't compile the project because I need to extend HttpServlet...).

I see it might not be correct to add the servlet jar as a 'compile' dependency, but rather like this:

```
providedCompile 'javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0-alpha-1'
```

but still the same NoSuchMethod exception gets thrown.

What's the right way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> [`javax.servlet:servlet-api:3.0-alpha-1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api/3.0-alpha-1)

This is the first alpha release of Servlet 3.0. This is far, very far from the final release. The particular alpha release indeed didn't contain the mentioned method yet. You can easily confirm it yourself by extracting the JAR file in question using a ZIP tool and inspecting the source and class file.

You need [`javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1) instead to have the final release of the Servlet 3.0 API.